How can I use socks5 proxy in puppeteer
Hey i have been trying to connect socks5 proxy to puppeteer but it's throwing me this error NO SUPPORTED PROXY.. sorry am using phone to ask questionss,
I would have sent the screenshot and code... But I was fetching my proxys from a proxy.json and use them in my action.js code and that's when it's throw me an error.. Anyone knows how can I by any chance any example of how I can use or manage to use, socks5 proxy with puppeteer nodejs with any example simple codes
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const { Person } = require("../../../HUMAN MODEL/personality.js"); 
    // Ensure this path is correct
   //const Behavior = require("../../BEHAVIOR MODEL/actions.js"); // 
   Ensure this path is correct
  //const behavior = require("../../BEHAVIOR MODEL/yt_direct.js");
  const Behavior = require("../../../BEHAVIOR MODEL/yt_search.js");



  // Load proxy settings from proxy.json
  const proxyPath = 'E:\\WORK PLACE\\Traffic 
  Bot\\Devices\\Iphones\\iphone 15 pro max\\proxy.json';
  let proxySettings;

  try {
const proxyData = fs.readFileSync(proxyPath, 'utf-8');
proxySettings = JSON.parse(proxyData);

// Log the loaded proxy settings
console.log('Proxy settings loaded:', proxySettings);

// Validate required proxy fields
if (!proxySettings.proxyServer || !proxySettings.proxyUsername || !proxySettings.proxyPassword || !proxySettings.timezone) {
    throw new Error("Proxy settings missing required fields.");
 }
 } catch (error) {
console.error('Error reading or validating proxy settings:', 
error.message);
process.exit(1);
}

const modeled = {
"Account": {
    "fullname": "maarin",
    "email": "your_email@example.com", // Add your email here
    "password": "your_password" // Add your password here
},
"cookie": [],
"LocalStorage": [],
"cookieType": "Youtube",
"Device": {
    "resolution": {
        "width": 430,
        "height": 932
    },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/7.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 18_7; iPhone 15 Pro Max) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/432.0.8702.51 Mobile/15E148 Safari/804.17",
    "isMobile": true,
    "hasTouch": true,
    //"timezone": proxySettings.timezone,
    "deviceName": "Apple iPhone 15 Pro Max"
},
"Location": {
    "proxyType": proxySettings.proxyType,
    "proxyServer": proxySettings.proxyServer,
    "proxyUsername": proxySettings.proxyUsername,
    "proxyPassword": proxySettings.proxyPassword,
},
"memo": {
    "about": "I am a Female from Nigeria",
    "device": "I am currently using the Apple iPhone 15 Pro Max"
}
};

 async function runBot() {
  try {
    const teebot = new Person('maarin_cookies.json');

    // Configure the bot
    teebot.modelAccount(modeled.Account);
    teebot.modelDevice(modeled.Device);
    teebot.modelLocation(modeled.Location); 
    teebot.modelcookie(modeled.cookie);
    teebot.showBrowser(true); // Set headless to true/false as needed

    
    console.log("Starting bot life...");
    let teebotBrowserPage = await teebot.startLife(modeled);  

    console.log("Bot started successfully.");

    // Log in to Google
    await teebot.loginToGoogle();

    // Instantiate the Behavior class and perform actions
    const actions = new Behavior(teebotBrowserPage);
    await actions.directVisit();

    // Set a valid URL to visit
    const urlToVisit = "https://whatismyipaddress.com/";
    console.log("URL to visit:", urlToVisit);
    
    await actions.directVisit(urlToVisit);

    // Export human model data
    await teebot.exportHuman(modeled);

    // Close the browser
    await teebot.close();
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during bot execution:', error.message);
}
}

    runBot();

the code above is the one that run the bot,and the code below is my personality js:
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const fs = require('fs');
   const path = require('path');



    // Ensure the directory for cookies exists
   async function ensureDirectory(dir) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
    }
  }


  // Function to wait for a specified amount of time
 function sleep(ms) {
return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

 // Function to type text in a human-like manner
 async function humanLikeTyping(page, selector, text) {
await page.focus(selector);
for (const char of text) {
    await page.keyboard.type(char);
    await sleep(Math.random() * 200 + 100); // Random delay between 
100ms and 300ms
}
}

 class Person {
 constructor(cookiesFileName) {
    this.browser = null;
    this.page = null;
    this.account = {};
    this.device = {};
    this.location = {};
    this.cookiesFileName = cookiesFileName || 'cookies.json';
    this.cookiesDir = path.join(__dirname, 'cookies');
    this.headless = false; // Default to headless mode
  }

  async startLife(modeled = {}) {
    await ensureDirectory(this.cookiesDir); // Ensure directory 
 exists

    // Debugging log for the modeled object
    console.log("Modeled object received in startLife:", 
  JSON.stringify(modeled, null, 2));

   
    if (!modeled.Location || !modeled.Location.proxyUsername || 
   !modeled.Location.proxyPassword || !modeled.Location.proxyServer) 
   {
        console.error("Missing proxy configuration in the modeled 
   object:", JSON.stringify(modeled.Location, null, 2));
        throw new Error('Missing proxy configuration in the modeled 
 object.');
    }

    console.log("Proxy configuration exists. Proceeding with 
  Puppeteer launch...");

    const proxyUrl =`socks5://${modeled.Location.proxyUsername}:${modeled.Location.proxyPassword}@${modeled.Location.proxyServer}`;

    this.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: this.headless,
        timeout: 60000, // Increase timeout to 60 seconds
        args: [
            '--proxy-server=socks5://localhost:1081',
            '--proxy-server=socks5://‘proxy-host’:‘proxy-port’',
            `--proxy-server=${proxyUrl}`, // Use the proxy URL
            `--window-size=${this.device.resolution.width || 1200},${this.device.resolution.height || 800}`,
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-extensions',
            '--disable-default-apps',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--no-zygote',
            '--single-process',
            '--hide-scrollbars',
            '--disable-infobars',
            '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--disable-features=BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests'
        ]
    });

    console.log("Puppeteer launched successfully.");

    this.page = await this.browser.newPage();
    await this.page.setBypassCSP(true);

    await this.page.setViewport({
        width: this.device.resolution?.width || 1200,
        height: this.device.resolution?.height || 800,
        isMobile: this.device.isMobile || false,
        hasTouch: this.device.hasTouch || false,
    });

    if (this.device.userAgent) {
        console.log("Setting user agent:", this.device.userAgent);
        await this.page.setUserAgent(this.device.userAgent);
    }

    // Set timezone
    if (this.device.timezone) {
        console.log("Emulating timezone:", this.device.timezone);
        await this.page.emulateTimezone(this.device.timezone);
    }

    // Load cookies if they exist
    console.log("Loading cookies...");
    await this.loadCookies();
    console.log("Cookies loaded.");

    return this.page;
}

async loginToGoogle() {
    try {
        console.log('Entering email...');
        await humanLikeTyping(this.page, 'input[type="email"]', this.account.email);
        await this.page.click('#identifierNext');
        await sleep(3000);

        console.log('Entering password...');
        await this.page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]', { visible: true });
        await humanLikeTyping(this.page, 'input[type="password"]', this.account.password);
        await this.page.click('#passwordNext');
        await this.page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

        console.log(`${this.account.email} logged in successfully.`);
        await this.saveCookies();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error logging in:', error);
    }
}

modelAccount(account) {
    console.log("Modeling account:", account);
    this.account = account;
}

modelDevice(device) {
    console.log("Modeling device:", device);
    this.device = device;
}

modelLocation(location) {
    console.log("Modeling location with proxy settings:", location);
    this.location = location;
    if (location.proxyServer) {
        const proxyUrl = `socks5://${location.proxyUsername}:${location.proxyPassword}@${location.proxyServer}`;
        process.env.HTTP_PROXY = proxyUrl;
        process.env.HTTPS_PROXY = proxyUrl;
    }
}

modelcookie(cookies) {
    console.log("Modeling cookies:", cookies);
    this.cookies = cookies;
}

showBrowser(show) {
    console.log(`Setting headless mode to: ${!show}`);
    this.headless = !show;
}

async exportHuman(modeled) {
    fs.writeFileSync('humanModel.json', JSON.stringify(modeled, null, 2));
    console.log("Human model exported.");
}

async saveCookies() {
    try {
        if (this.page) {
            const cookies = await this.page.cookies();
            const cookiesPath = path.join(this.cookiesDir, this.cookiesFileName);
            fs.writeFileSync(cookiesPath, JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 2));
            console.log(`Cookies saved to ${cookiesPath}.`);
        } else {
            console.error('Cannot save cookies, page is closed.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving cookies:', error);
    }
}

async loadCookies() {
    try {
        const cookiesPath = path.join(this.cookiesDir, this.cookiesFileName);
        if (fs.existsSync(cookiesPath)) {
            const cookies = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(cookiesPath));
            await this.page.setCookie(...cookies);
            console.log(`Cookies loaded from ${cookiesPath}.`);
        } else {
            console.log('No cookies file found.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading cookies:', error);
    }
}

async close() {
    try {
        await this.saveCookies();
        if (this.browser) {
            await this.browser.close();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error closing browser:', error);
    }
  }
 }

module.exports = { Person };


now this is my proxyjson file:
    {
"proxyType": "socks5",
"proxyServer": "socks5://8888:8",
"proxyUsername": "my username",
"proxyPassword": "my pass word",
"timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
   }


Please share your code and full stack trace as a [mcve]. Without that it's difficult to help.

hey i have edited my question with the code embedded

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hey i want to use socks5 proxy but when I run my codes on top.. I have an error of NO SUPPORTED PROXY

According to the Proxy support in Chrome documentation, you should simply use --proxy-server="socks5://host:port" replacing host and port with your proxy information.
However, Chrome does not support credentials being passed via --proxy-server, therefore proxies requiring authentication must be authorized via credential resolution flow. See the snippet below from the documentation:

Chrome does not implement this, and will not use any credentials embedded in the proxy settings.

Proxy authentication will instead go through the ordinary flow to find credentials.

Looking at my codes, what can I replace for me to use socks5 from my proxy.json what can I change or what can be replaced from all the codes I shared.. For me to not receive NO SUPPORTED PROXY
